# XSLT grouping / counting attributes based on element value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need some hints on how to solve this best:

Say I have the following XML given:

```
<drink count="2">beer</drink>
<drink count="1">wine</drink>
<drink count="3">beer</drink>
```

The count should be summed and the value grouped, i.e. like this:

```
Beer: 5
Wine: 1
```

What's the best approach for this? Is this possible with XSLT even?

Thanks in advnace

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: your message was not helpful really, it was not solved without grouping anyway

Comment: I am afraid you're not being clear.